Custom image is not being predicted correctly in MNIST neural network model from scratch
Accuracy =  92.29285714285714 % on test data but custom image is predicting incorrectly. I have tried multiple numbers. Am I doing preprocessing of custom image wrong? Or simple feedforward neural network isn't powerful enough to detect random generalized data ? Maybe CNN is able to predict this.


2 Hidden layers with 16 neurons each
learning rate = 0.01
iterations = 20000
activation functions = Relu on hidden layers and softmax on output
layer
70000 total dataset out of which 56000 used for training and 14000 used for testing

Code
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import cv2
import time

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

def relu_derivative(x):
    return np.where(x > 0, 1, 0)

def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / sum(np.exp(x))

def initialize_parameters(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size_1, hidden_layer_size_2, output_layer_size):
    w1 = np.random.rand(hidden_layer_size_1, input_layer_size) - 0.5
    b1 = np.random.rand(hidden_layer_size_1, 1) - 0.5
    w2 = np.random.rand(hidden_layer_size_2, hidden_layer_size_1) - 0.5
    b2 = np.random.rand(hidden_layer_size_2, 1) - 0.5
    w3 = np.random.rand(output_layer_size, hidden_layer_size_2) - 0.5
    b3 = np.random.rand(output_layer_size, 1) - 0.5
    return w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3

def forward_propagation(x, w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3):
    z1 = np.dot(w1, x.T) + b1
    a1 = relu(z1)
    z2 = np.dot(w2, a1) + b2
    a2 = relu(z2)
    z3 = np.dot(w3, a2) + b3
    a3 = softmax(z3)
    return z1, a1, z2, a2, z3, a3

def loss(y, a3):
    m = y.shape[0]
    loss_value = np.sum(((y.T - a3) ** 2)) / m
    return loss_value

def backward_propagate(x, y, z1, a1, z2, a2, a3, w2, w3):
    m = x.shape[0]

    dz3 = a3 - y.T
    dw3 = np.dot(dz3, a2.T) / m
    db3 = np.sum(dz3) / m

    da2 = np.dot(w3.T, dz3)
    dz2 = da2 * relu_derivative(z2)
    dw2 = np.dot(dz2, a1.T) / m
    db2 = np.sum(dz2) / m

    da1 = np.dot(w2.T, dz2)
    dz1 = da1 * relu_derivative(z1)
    dw1 = np.dot(dz1, x) / m
    db1 = np.sum(dz1) / m

    return dw1, db1, dw2, db2, dw3, db3

def update_parameters(w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3, dw1, db1, dw2, db2, dw3, db3, learning_rate):
    w1 -= learning_rate * dw1
    b1 -= learning_rate * db1
    w2 -= learning_rate * dw2
    b2 -= learning_rate * db2
    w3 -= learning_rate * dw3
    b3 -= learning_rate * db3

    return w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3

def train(x, y, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size_1, hidden_layer_size_2, output_layer_size, learning_rate, iterations):
    w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3 = initialize_parameters(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size_1, hidden_layer_size_2, output_layer_size)

    for i in range(iterations):
        z1, a1, z2, a2, z3, a3 = forward_propagation(x, w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3)
        loss_value = loss(y, a3)
        dw1, db1, dw2, db2, dw3, db3 = backward_propagate(x, y, z1, a1, z2, a2, a3, w2, w3)
        w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3 = update_parameters(w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3, dw1, db1, dw2, db2, dw3, db3, learning_rate)

        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Iteration {i}, Loss: {loss_value}")

    return w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3

def main():
    mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
    x, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']

    x = np.array(x, dtype='float32')
    y = np.array(y, dtype='int32')
    x /= 255.0

    num_classes = 10
    y_onehot = np.zeros((y.shape[0], num_classes))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        y_onehot[i, y[i]] = 1

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y_onehot, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    
    input_layer_size = x_train.shape[1]
    hidden_layer_size_1 = 16
    hidden_layer_size_2 = 16
    output_layer_size = num_classes
    learning_rate = 0.01
    iterations = 20000

    start = time.time()
    w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3 = train(x_train, y_train, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size_1, hidden_layer_size_2, output_layer_size, learning_rate, iterations)
    end = time.time()
    print("total time to train model", end - start, "seconds")
    np.savez("mnist_params.npz", w1=w1, b1=b1, w2=w2, b2=b2, w3=w3, b3=b3)

    _, _, _, _, _, y_predict = forward_propagation(x_test, w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3)
    accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(y_predict.T, axis=1) == np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)) * 100
    print("Accuracy = ", accuracy, " % ")

    img = cv2.imread("images/7.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off') 
    plt.show()
    img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')  
    plt.show()
    img = img.flatten()
    img = np.array(img, dtype='float32')
    img /= 255.0
    img = img.reshape(1, -1)

    params = np.load('mnist_params.npz')
    _, _, _, _, _, y_predict = forward_propagation(img, params['w1'], params['b1'], params['w2'], params['b2'], params['w3'], params['b3'])
    print(y_predict)
    print(np.argmax(y_predict))
   
main()


This image is too different from the images in MNIST, a model trained on MNIST will never generalize on this image.

does it mean 70k is not enough data to build a generalize model ? Or CNN should be used to also train relationship between features because I am watching a tutorial of CNN in which they are saying that even if you disturb the position of image in feedforward they will have difficulty predicting it ?

It means MNIST is an academic dataset and not meant to build a general handwritten character recognition model.
